# Regular Expression to add quotes to CSV columns without quotes

Tags: php, csv

I've got data in a CSV, and I can't change the formatting.

Some of the columns have double quotes, others have no quotes.

The only problem, and the reason I need to add double quotes in the first place, is that some of the columns have numbers with commas, but no double quotes around them - this is causing the CSV processing to break.

Is there a way to differentiate between these two types of commas in a regular expression?

Here's part of a sample row in the data currently:

```
"NasdaqNM","-0.06 - -0.27%",19.00,25.75,1.04,1.28,0.50,21.75,17.67,1.97,6.652,3.40,1.77,95.2M,21.7642,22.8678,6,402," ====== "
```

As you can notice, at the 6,402, which should be one number, it will split into two.

So I guess my question is - is there a way to analyze the commas in the CSV and generate double quotes for the correct columns?

I'm using PHP.

Comment: How do you know the `6,402` should be one number?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. No.
It's not possible to differentiate those 2 cases.

Simple quiz:
How many numbers are here: `1,2,3,4,5` ?

You can't tell? So your PC also won't be able to do that.

You need to quote comma containing data, or exchange comma for dot.

If you know that specific 2 columns are one number you can try to merge them post parse.